# change the String of a file'path in Java

Tags: java, css, regex, string, replace

As it mentioned in the topic, is there a way to change the String of a file's path in java?
For example:

```
  String fileName = "scripts/css/an.main.master.css";
```

How can I just keep the file's name “an.main.master.css” and change the folder path "scripts/css" to whatever I want? In other word, how can I detect the last backslash(the substring after that slash will be the file's name, and the substring before that slash will be the path). I am thinking to using Regular Expression, but I am not good at this. Can anyone help?

Comment: You could use `fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/")++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If regular expression is the way you want to go..

If you want to retain the last forward slash replacing everything before it:

```
String s = "scripts/css/an.main.master.css";
String r = s.replaceAll("^.*(?=/)", "foo");
// => "foo/an.main.master.css"
```

Or if you want the last forward slash removed as well:

```
String s = "scripts/css/an.main.master.css";
String r = s.replaceAll("^.*/", "foo/");
//=> "foo/an.main.master.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

REgex:

```
^(.*/)(.*)$
```

Replace:

```
string$2
```

`string` -  string you want to replace.

Java code would be,

```
String fileName = "scripts/css/an.main.master.css";
String m1 = fileName.replaceAll("^(.*/)(.*)$", "string $2");
System.out.println(m1);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/yGCn6J)